# Sinatra (or maybe not) issue on redirect; parameters passing to subsequent request

Tags: http, browser, sinatra

Something wrong is happening. I have a get endpoint which takes some parameters, does something and then redirects to '/'. Response generated by Sinatra before invoke looks good (right 'location' header with right url). Problem is, the browser, despite redirecting to '/', is appending the parameters from the previous request to the url. That means, if I refresh, it fails. Can someone tell me exactly what is going on? I thought the problem was Sinatra, but it also might have to do with the browser.

EDIT:

```
get '/connect' do
  puts params[:code]
  redirect to('/')
end
```

this is the route. basically, it's the redirection endpoint of an oauth workflow for a certain oauth service provider. Instead of being redirected to '/', I end up being redirected to '/#code=blablabla', which means, the query parameters from my oauth endpoint are being passed around as hash parameters to the subsequent redirect.

Comment: Do you mind sharing code? ATM its like shooting in the dark.

Comment: Have you issued this here on GitHub already?: https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues/596

Comment: I did, but would like to keep the subject open on both places to reach more people.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Soundcloud Oauth implementation: Why the hash parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14307517/soundcloud-oauth-implementation-why-the-hash-parameters)